# Import error while calling from IIS hosted .NET Core API

Tags: python, iis, visual-c++, asp.net-core, pyrfc

I am facing the below issue while running a python script from a .NET Core api which is hosted in windows server IIS .I am using pyrfc 1.9.5 SAP connector in this script. Here is the code below

```
from pyrfc import Connection
def GetConnection(connmeta):
   return Connection(**connmeta)
```

Here is the error which I got -

```
from pyrfc import Connection
  File "<C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyrfc-1.9.5-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\pyrfc_init_.py>", line 22, in 
    from pyrfc._pyrfc import get_nwrfclib_version, Connection, TypeDescription, FunctionDescription, Server
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

It's working fine from the command prompt, python IDLE, Powershell etc. Previously I got this error when the visual c++ redistributable package was not installed. But now it is installed properly as the same script is working from IDLE and Powershell.

Here are the installed software and server details -

- windows server 2016 64 bit
- Visual C++ 2013 redistributable 64 bit
- Python 3.5 64 bit,
- pyrfc 1.9.5 for python 3.5 64 bit (amd64)
- SAP NW RFC SDK 7.5.0 64 bit

Python executable and the path to the `lib` folder of the SDK is already added to the Environment variable. I have also tried to execute the sample rfcexec.exe program from the `bin` directory it's working fine. **I am only getting the error while running the application from IIS.** The app pool identity has full permission on the python scripts.

The script is working fine from IIS if I comment the pyrfc import part.
Please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution after debugging for atleast 1 week. The problem was access related issue. the SAP NW RFC SDK was installed in the path `C:\nwrfcsdk\lib` as per the documentation.

link : [Installation documentation](http://sap.github.io/PyRFC/install.html)

But the user account under which the .NET Core API was running in the application pool of IIS **didn't have any read/write access** to this `nwrfcsdk` folder. Hence pyrfc was not able to import the DLL (SAPNWRFC.dll) when the python script was being called from the .NET Core API.I have provided read/write access to that particular account and the script is running fine now .

I have followed the below steps to debug the diagnose the issue -

- I have used profiling with **Procmon.exe** from sysinternals to monitor w3wp.exe IIS worker process and python.exe after calling the API
- I have also used dependency walker to track the dependent dll.

Hope this helps someone who is facing a similar type of issue.